# Reducing space between two box() in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

the given script generates a simple histogram plot and a slider within two boxes. I wish to reduce the space between the two boxes and also between their extreme borders with the ends of the screen. Please help and thanks.[snapshot of the plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMcOT.png)

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 0
),
dashboardBody(
# Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
fluidRow(
box(title = "Activity Frequency", status = "primary",height = "520", 
solidHeader = T,
plotOutput("plot1")),
box(title = "Activity Frequency", status = "primary",height = "520", 
solidHeader = T,
sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50))
)
)
)
server <- function(input, output) {
set.seed(122)
histdata <- rnorm(500)
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
hist(data)
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: To reduce the padding, you could add `tags$head(tags$style(HTML("div.col-sm-6 {padding:1px}"))),` into `dashboardBody`.

Comment: Salute Sir, perfectly works, would greatly appreciate if you can help me from  reducing size from right and left side of box to the screen end.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with that.

Comment: @lukeA, need a similar but a little different help with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154749/changing-the-width-height-and-alignment-of-the-shiny-widgets-in-r?noredirect=1#comment81263002_47154749

Answer (score 2):

The answer in the comments did not work for me. After some trial and error, what worked was this:

```
dashboardBody(tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
.box {margin: 5px;}'
)))
```

Just include `.box {margin: 5px;}` in your HTML style tags.